# How to store array in const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

i know my question is not clear, my question is, i want to print my array using map in JSX, but i dont want to do this in several times in same page so how to solve this issue

also how to add id in Link

**my code is**

```
<ul>
    <li><b>Admin info</b></li>
            {users.items && users.items.map((item,i) => <li key={i}>{item.email}</li>)}
    <li><Link to="/admin/5c4f69d5259f7d14434b4cb6">Admin pass and info {data}</Link></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
     <li><b>Company Info</b></li>
     <li>Company Profile </li>
     <li>Billing Address and Billing contact</li>
     <li> {users.items && users.items.map((item,i) => <li key={i}>{item.email}</li>)}</li>
    <li></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: You know your question is not clear and still, it is not clear lol.

Comment: :) is it good deal to map several times in a single page, how to do this in proper way

Comment: Map your result in a constant and use it wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since the map return value is same, you can make it into a component if it can be used in other components too

```
const MapComponent = ({users}) => (
    return users.items && users.items.map((item,i) => <li key={i}>{item.email}</li>)
)
```

and use it like

```
    <ul>
        <li><b>Admin info</b></li>
        <MapComponent users={users} />
        <li><Link to="/admin/5c4f69d5259f7d14434b4cb6">Admin pass and info {data}</Link></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><b>Company Info</b></li>
        <li>Company Profile </li>
        <li>Billing Address and Billing contact</li>
        <li> <MapComponent users={users} /></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
```

or else store it in a variable in render method

```
render() {
      const userItems = users.items && users.items.map((item,i) => <li key={i}>{item.email}</li>)
      return (
           <ul>
            <li><b>Admin info</b></li>
            {userItems}
            <li><Link to="/admin/5c4f69d5259f7d14434b4cb6">Admin pass and info {data}</Link></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><b>Company Info</b></li>
            <li>Company Profile </li>
            <li>Billing Address and Billing contact</li>
            <li> {userItems}</li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
     )
}
```

If the content has to change, you can make use of render props pattern

```
const MapComponent = ({data, children}) => (
    return data && data.map((item,i) => children(item))
)
```

and use like

```
    <ul>
        <li><b>Admin info</b></li>
        <MapComponent data={users.item}>
           {(item) => <li key={i}>{item.email}</li>}
        </MapComponent>
        <li><Link to="/admin/5c4f69d5259f7d14434b4cb6">Admin pass and info {data}</Link></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><b>Company Info</b></li>
        <li>Company Profile </li>
        <li>Billing Address and Billing contact</li>
        <li> 
            <MapComponent data={users.item}>
                 {(item) => (
                      <ul><li>{item.name}</li><li>{item.email}</li></ul> 
                 )}
            </MapComponent>
        </li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: i also want {item.name} in another li , then what will do ?

Comment: If the returned content has to change, you need to specify it separately. What you can do though is to make it in a renderProps pattern

Answer (score 0):

Say your code is in render, then you can store the result of map temporarily in a variable and use it in different place as shown below

```
render() {
  const mappedItems = users.items && users.items.map((item,i) => <li key={i}>{item.email}</li>);
  return (
   <ul>
        <li><b>Admin info</b></li>
        {mappedItems}
        <li><Link to="/admin/5c4f69d5259f7d14434b4cb6">Admin pass and info {data}</Link></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><b>Company Info</b></li>
        <li>Company Profile </li>
        <li>Billing Address and Billing contact</li>
        <li>{mappedItems}</li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: i also want {item.name} in another li , then what will do ?

Comment: In that case, you can make use of @Shubham's method and send an argument and conditionally render it.